Pyflink process died with exit code 0 without paral parallelism set to 1
Context
I'm facing problem while running flink on minCluster with python
Code snippet is:
from pyflink.common import WatermarkStrategy, Row
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.number_seq import NumberSequenceSource


def state_access_demo():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    # env.set_parallelism(1)
    seq_num_source = NumberSequenceSource(1, 10000)
    ds = env.from_source(
        source=seq_num_source,
        watermark_strategy=WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps(),
        source_name='seq_num_source',
        type_info=Types.LONG())

    ds = ds.map(lambda a: Row(a % 4, 1), output_type=Types.ROW([Types.LONG(), Types.LONG()])) \
           .key_by(lambda a: a[0]) \
           .print()

    env.execute('state_access_demo')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    state_access_demo()

Then I get:
Failed to create stage bundle factory! INFO:root:Initializing Python harness: <local_path>env\Lib\site-packages\pyflink\fn_execution\beam\beam_boot.py --id=6-1 --provision_endpoint=localhost:64985
INFO:root:Starting up Python harness in loopback mode.

        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:656)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:281)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.java:57)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.java:85)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:117)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.ExternalPythonProcessOperator.open(ExternalPythonProcessOperator.java:64)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:107)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:734)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:709)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:675)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:952)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:921)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:745)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 0
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:654)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 0
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:75)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:252)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:231)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 23 more

Question
When I uncomment env.set_parallelism(1) it all works fine.
Why do I face issue with parallelismset to 1?
Env:

Windows 11
apache_flink==1.17.2
apache_flink_libraries==1.17.2
python 3.11.9

Error free flow without calling env.set_parallelism(1)
